# Footer as floated divs with centered content - stay center when zoom out

Tags: html, css

Here is my simple footer (upper- zoom:100%, below- zoom:70%) :

[image]

It could be very simple, if i had center content with single `div` fixed `width` and `margin: 0 auto` and same color for outer footer layout.

But, there are two divs, with `float: left` and they couldn't have fixed width, but content should stay centered when zoom out.

Is there any examples of html & css markup like this?

Ty.

Comment: Can you add tha actual HTML and CSS? or make a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to view instead? that would help us in getting you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for your divs inside footer :

```
div.footeritem 
{
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JLeGN/   no matter how mutch zoom in or zoom out the content stays in center